# Streaming high quality videos without loss of quality?

Tags: itunes, ipad, video, streaming

Is there any software on PC/Mac which just 'serves' the files of system to iPad (instead of converting them on the fly) and any app which is able to play such content?

I tried Plex, though it streams most of the videos, but quality isn't great. And I have even enabled Direct Play  which as per description :

> Allows the player to play compatible media without any conversion. In
>   most browsers, direct play supports MP4 videos with h264 video and AAC
>   audio. Videos with subtitles cannot be played directly.

However the quality isn't same when I compare the same file in AvPlayerHD. I tried a 12GB MKV 1080p video, I felt quality was far superior in AvPlayerHD as compared to streaming.

Basically I don't want to convert and use CPU of my PC, when my iPad is perfectly capable of playing such quality content, why convert at all?

So is there any app which does that? And also I heard Air Video does this, but I couldn't find any info.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Air Video HD](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-video-hd/id668354926) (US$3) and the [free server for OS X](http://inmethod.com/airvideohd).

Comment: Can you comment anything about quality of the video stream? Have you tried streaming 1080p MKVs of size 10-12GB?

Comment: I have streamed MKVs of that size and larger (Blu-Ray rips), and have had no problem with the quality on my iPad 3. My Mac mini seems to be able to serve several streams at once to various devices around the house. Do I see an occasional glitch or artifact? Yes, but it’s usually momentary and not frequent enough to bother me, and my wife will tell you that I am easily annoyed. YMMV, of course, and it’s possible that your threshold is even lower than mine. If so, you're out $3. But compared to the time, disk space, and hassle of transcoding and copying, I'll take Air Video any day.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried nPlayer? That's what I use right now, allows streaming and great quality of the videos I watch.